# Program that determines whether an int is greater or lesser

Tags: code-challenge

Write a program which prompts a user to input two integers A and B, the program should determine whether A is greater than or lesser than B without the use of greater than [>] or less than [<] operators (and similar operators or methods like .compare) and should output :

```
Integer A is greater than B.



Rules  : No Brainfuck.
```

Should work for negative numbers.  Signed int. Code's for equality isn't necessary.

Edited Again.

Comment: Is this supposed to be code golf? Otherwise it's a trivial question.

Comment: What size int? Signed or unsigned? And where's the challenge? Looks pretty trivial to me.

Comment: Actually, as written, `return a!=b` could be argued to meet the spec (it determines whether `a` is (greater than or less than) `b`).

Comment: As it stands this is too underspecified to make a viable problem in my eyes. −1 from me until this is rectified.

Comment: I take back the bit about being pretty trivial, given the number of people submitting buggy answers.

Comment: I've edited the Q

Comment: Why do we need to say that A is greater than B *and* B is less than  A? Surely one can't be true without the other?

Comment: Oh. Crap. Sorry.

Comment: What size int? What if they're equal?

Comment: Does this include bit shift operators (<< and >>)?

Comment: does `min` fall into "and similar operators or methods like .compare" ?

Comment: Of-course, it does.

Comment: Why no brainfuck? What exactly is a "similar" operator to `<` and `>`?

Answer (score 10):

### Javascript

Here's the basic format of all the solutions.  This case returns `true` if `a>b` and `false` otherwise:

```
function greaterThan(a,b){
    c=a;//Copy a
    while(true){
        if(b==a){
            return false;
        }
        if(b==c){
            return true;
        }
        a++;//Approaches b if a<b
        c--;//Approaches b if a>b
    }
}
```

**Warning:**  Since we didn't need to support the `A==B` case, the next 3 solutions will lock up for those inputs.  Thus, don't fill in equal or empty numbers at the prompts in the test fiddles, unless of course you like pushing red buttons that say "Do **NOT** push!!!"

**149 chars** - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/aEDX6/): Conforms EXACTLY to specs ;)

`for(A=B='A',C='B',a=c=prompt(A),b=prompt(C);b!=c++||(B=C),b!=a--||(A=C),A==B;);alert("Integer "+B+" is Greater than "+A+".\n\n\nRules  : No Brainfuck.")`

**74 chars** - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/DxpwK/): Prompts user for 2 numbers, alerts '-1' if 1st<2nd, '1' if 2nd>1st:

```
for(A=0,a=c=prompt(),b=prompt();b!=c++||(A=-1),b!=a--||(A=1),!A;);alert(A)
```

**54 chars** - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/SK3X2/): Function that takes 2 parameters and returns `true` if `A > B`, `false` if `A < B`, and, of course, locks up if `A==B`.

```
function a(a,b){for(c=a;b!=++a&&b!=--c;);return b!=a;}
```

Comment: How about with decimals?

Comment: "Function that takes 2 parameters and returns true if A > B, false if B < A"   ... A>B and B<A are the same thing :)

Comment: @imoda: The current solution definitely won't work with decimals.  However, it could be modified to work with decimals to a certain precision by adding/subtracting by that precision instead of 1.  However, because JavaScript uses floats, the max number you can check will approximately be multiplied by that precision.  e.g. `1000000000000001==1000000000000001`, `10000000000000001==10000000000000000`, `1.000000000000001==1.000000000000001`, `1.0000000000000001==1`

Comment: Although this is not a code golf question, I would like to challenge you :) `function a(a,b){return((a-b)/Math.abs(a-b))==1}` - 47 bytes.

Comment: @pimvdb:  Challenge accepted!  Not sure if `Math.abs` is allowed, but if so how about:  `function a(a,b){return a-b-Math.abs(a-b)}` - 41 bytes, or if `false` and `true` are required:  `function a(a,b){return 0==a-b-Math.abs(a-b)}` - 44 bytes

Comment: @Briguy37: Nicely found. `Math.abs` is perhaps not completely fair, but you win anyway.

Comment: @pimvdb: Also, just found `function a(a,b)a-b-Math.abs(a-b)` - 32 bytes, but that only works in Firefox :)

Answer (score 6):

## Python

```
from sys import argv as s
a,b=int(s[1]), int(s[2])
if a==b:
 print 'They are the same!'
else:
 print 'Integer A is greater than B.' if (abs(a-b)==a-b) else 'Integer B is greater than A.'
```

## Python -  73 characters

if inputs as arguments is acceptable as 'input', it is only 73 characters:

```
def c(a,b):
 if a==b:
  return 'They are the same!'
 else:
  return 'Integer A is greater than B.' if (abs(a-b)==a-b) else 'Integer B is greater than A.'
```

if the weak inequality is all we care about, and we don't have to take input, it's shorter (33 characters):

```
print a if (abs(a-b)==a-b) else b
```

Comment: "Write a program" would seem to imply that more than a function is required. But then it's code-challenge rather than code-golf, so length isn't so important.

Comment: good point. I switched the order of my responses.

Comment: btw.: It's not a golf.

Comment: What output do you get for `2000000000, -2000000000`?

Comment: "Integer A is greater than B."

Answer (score 5):

### C

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a, b;
    long long c;
    double d;
    printf("A: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("B: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    c = (long long)a - (long long)b;
    if (c == 0) {
        puts("Integer A is equal to B.");
    }
    else {
        d = *(double*)&c;
        if (d == d) {
            puts("Integer A is greater than B.");
        }
        else {
            puts("Integer B is greater than A.");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It was golfed but then I realized this wasn't a golf. So now it's not. ;)

To understand how this works, you have to understand how numbers are integers and floats are represented, bitwise, and how the CPU operates on them.

I'm starting out by getting two 32-bit signed integers. They are stored as ints to bound the input. I then cast them to long longs, basically converting them to 64-bit integers, and then subtract. This subtraction is important. If A is larger than B, the result will be positive. If they're equal, the result is 0, and if B is larger than A, the result is negative. The negative case is the key, here, because of how it's represented as an integer in memory. A negative integer is stored as a 2's complement, and since these are 64-bit integers, we'll have at least one DWord of 1s in the MSBs in memory. I then store that into a 64-bit double variable, turning it into a double value with the same bit encoding. If it is negative, this double value is a NaN. By IEEE floating point rules, comparing a NaN with itself will always result in `false`, which indicates that A < B.

And of course, a simple zero check can add an equivalence check to the algorithm.

**EDIT:** This now works for very large and very small ints. It requires a 64-bit compiler, where `long long` is defined as having a size of 8 bytes. Unfortunately, gcc in Cygwin didn't do the trick, so I had to use Visual Studio. But, it works. <strike>This, I found, does not work for very large and very small 32-bit integers. I will be investigating a solution.</strike>

Comment: `When the CPU operates on a NaN, it will flip some of the bits to be only the ones that need to be 0 for it to be considered a NaN.` Doesn't this depend on the compiler flags and processor? There are different types of NaN for a reason.

Comment: @joey, @Peter Taylor: `c = (long long)a - (long long)b;` well, how is that different than my (removed) suggestion?

Comment: @Harry, it's promoting the 32-bit ints to 64 bits before doing the subtraction. That guarantees that it will stay in range.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: we don't understand each other :lol: What if a and b are defined as long long in the first place (now they are limited to values between INT_MIN - INT_MAX). Even with the revised specs I could for example legitimately claim that restricting the input values to such a small range is a bigger flaw than defining a and b as long long and don't check for overflowing. You see what I'm saying here? Unless you input a and b as strings to be converted later you can't control overflowing against the maximum representable integer in C.

Comment: @Peter Taylor It may, though this is default behavior for the Visual Studio compiler. At my workplace, we had to do some major modifications to our C/C++ code because of how NaNs were clobbered when passing them through the ALU (we needed the bits to be preserved). I didn't have to pass any special compiler flags to cl when building this code.

Comment: @Harry K. How would restricting them to 32-bit ints at input be a bigger flaw? The original specs call for two integers, not two long longs. Therefore, restricting them at input is fine. It may not be the most user-friendly (if you enter a larger number, it won't notify you) but in the end, the only input space we care about are within [INT_MIN, INT_MAX].

Comment: @Peter Taylor I just thought about this some more and no, it wouldn't really depend on special compiler flags as far as I know. QNaNs and SNaNs are always treated a certain way by the ALU in the CPU, and I don't believe that there's any way to change that, even programatically.

Comment: In theory there are traps you can set up, but I don't know whether the CPUs in actual use make them available, and if so whether compilers do. OTOH I've thought about it some more too and it's irrelevant whether the NaN is normalised or not, because it will still compare to be different to itself anyway.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, that is correct. You reminded me of that fact. It actually was something that I was unsure about, but I figured posting my reasoning here would clarify it. Happy coincidence that it worked. :) I confirmed that from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Floating_point). I'll update the reasoning to reflect this.

Comment: @sidran32: `How would restricting them to 32-bit ints at input be a bigger flaw? The original specs call for two integers, not two long longs` But, long longs are integers too :) The whole point is that in my eyes most of our efforts should not get shifted towards handling overflows, thus treating the key question as if it has a secondary role instead of being the protagonist. Anyway, Joey rolled back my original answer, making me happy again :) Nevertheless, it's always a pleasure to have discussions like these, I think we all benefit from them.

Comment: @Harry K. Ya, they are integers. Though in a programming context, I typically associate "integer" to mean a 32-bit integer type. Most languages that have an 'int' or 'integer' primitive assign it as such, so that assumption is valid, in my opinion. Though of course it would be better to be explicit if the poster specified the size in the requirements. :P And such discussions are always beneficial, so I agree with you there.

Answer (score 4):

### Python

```
r="less"
try:(input()-input())**.5;r="greater"
except:pass
print "Integer A is",r,"than B"
```

Answer (score 3):

### Scala

Based on the revised question:

```
object G extends App
{
    def g(i:BigInt,j:BigInt)=
    {
        def q(a:BigInt,b:BigInt):String=
        {
            if(a==0)
                "Integer B is greater than A."
            else 
                if(b==0)
                    "Integer A is greater than B."
                else
                    q(a+1,b-1)
        }
        if(i!=j)q(i-j,i-j)else"A and B are equal"
    }
    val(a,b)=(readLine("A: ").toInt,readLine("B: ").toInt)
    println(g(a,b))
}
```

Comment: The numbers should be read from the user somehow, at least that's how I understand »a number inputted«.

Comment: ` scala G
A: 2000000000
B: -2000000000
Integer B is greater than A.`

Comment: @user unknown I've changed to `BigInt`s to solve that, but when the numbers get that big, it's probably to slow to be useful anyway. Which is why they invented `<` and `>` I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Since most of the questions about the spec have been answered, here's a solution in C#. If the size of the ints isn't 32-bit then `int` needs changing for a suitable type.

```
namespace Sandbox {
    class Program {
        private static int _Compare(int a, int b) {
            if (a == b) return 0;
            int sgnA = (a & int.MinValue) == int.MinValue ? -1 : 1;
            int sgnB = (b & int.MinValue) == int.MinValue ? -1 : 1;
            // If they have different signs then the negative one is smaller.
            if (sgnA != sgnB) return sgnA;
            // If they're both non-negative then the difference won't overflow.
            // If they're both negative, then the different won't overflow. Worst case is (-1) - int.MinValue = int.MaxValue
            return ((a - b) & int.MinValue) == int.MinValue ? -1 : 1;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            if (args.Length == 0) {
                // Test mode.
                int[] cases = new int[] {
                    int.MinValue,
                    int.MinValue + 1,
                    int.MinValue + 2,
                    int.MinValue / 2 - 2,
                    int.MinValue / 2 - 1,
                    int.MinValue / 2,
                    int.MinValue / 2 + 1,
                    int.MinValue / 2 + 2,
                    -2, -1, 0, 1, 2,
                    int.MaxValue / 2 - 2,
                    int.MaxValue / 2 - 1,
                    int.MaxValue / 2,
                    int.MaxValue / 2 + 1,
                    int.MaxValue / 2 + 2,
                    int.MaxValue - 2,
                    int.MaxValue - 1,
                    int.MaxValue,
                };
                foreach (int _a in cases) {
                    foreach (int _b in cases) {
                        int _cmp = _Compare(_a, _b);
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", _a, _b, _cmp, _cmp == _a.CompareTo(_b) ? "OK" : "Error"));
                    }
                }
            }
            eise if (args.Length != 2) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Expected two arguments.");
            }
            else {
                int a, b;
                if (!int.TryParse(args[0], out a) || !int.TryParse(args[1], out b)) { Console.Error.WriteLine("Both arguments must be integers"); return; }

                int cmp = _Compare(a, b);
                Console.WriteLine(cmp == -1 ? "Integer A is less than B" : cmp == 0 ? "Integer A equals B" : "Integer A is greater than B");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of the test cases pass.

Answer (score 3):

### Scala:

```
object G extends Application {
  def g (a: Byte, b: Byte) = (a & -128, b & -128) match {
        case (0, 0) => if (((a - b) & -128) != 0) "<" else ">"
        case (x, 0) => "<"
        case (0, x) => ">"
        case _ => if (((b-a) & -128) != 0) ">" else "<"
  }
  val r = g (readByte, readByte)
  println ("A is " + (if (r==">") "greater than" else "less than") + " B")
}
```

Since `ints` vary from language to language, I choosed Bytes here, because it allowed me to do exhaustive testing.

Of course it can easily be adapted to short/int/long, with Int.MIN_VALUE etc. instead of -128.

The 4 cases test for

- both values are positive
- only first
- only second
- none of them

It took me 60 minutes to golf it down to 297 chars, until I noticed, that it isn't a golf! And another 10 minutes for hitting 80x `undo` (real programmers don't do backups).

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript: (108 chars without spaces)

```
function C(a,b) {
    var d=a-b,
        z=!!(d/Math.abs(d)+ 1),
        m=z?a:b,
        n=z?b:a;
    return 'Integer '+m+' is greater than '+n;
}
```

tests:

```
console.log( C (1, 3) );    // Integer 3 is greater than 1
console.log( C (3, 2) );    // Integer 3 is greater than 2
console.log( C (-3, -8) );  // Integer -3 is greater than -8
console.log( C (-9, 0) );   // Integer 0 is greater than -9
```

Code for equality is not required, so I didn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

### Ada, 76 Characters

```
function C(A,B:Integer)return Integer is
begin return (A-B)/abs(A-B);end C;
```

returns -1 for A smaller than B, and 1 for A bigger than B.

for A=B an exception will be raised, but the behaviour in this case isn't specified in the task description.

Answer (score 2):

### D (51 chars)

```
int d(int a,int b){return a-b?(a-b)&-1<<31?-1:1:0;}
```

using signed representation

returns `-1`,`0`,`1` for `less than`, `equals to` and `greater than` resp.

with reading from user: **91 chars**

```
import std.stdio;void main(){int a,b;readf("%d %d",&a,&b);writeln(a-b?(a-b)&-1<<31?-1:1:0);}
```

Comment: This isn't a golf, but you can shave a char by using (a-=b)?a ... (May not work in D, I'm not too familiar with it. Unfortunately it seems D has a boolean type, but otherwise you could shave chars by flipping your logic: `d(a,b){return(a-=b)&1<<31?-1:!!a;}`

Answer (score 1):

### PHP

PHP's too verbose for a task this simple, but I'm in PHP mode so I'll go ahead:

```
function d($a,$b){return $a-$b;}
// Returns a negative number if $a < $b, positive if $a > $b, 0 if $a == $b
```

If you need it to always return the same values, then

```
function d($a,$b){return ($d=$a-$b)?$d/abs($d):0;}
// Returns -1 if $a < $b, 1 if $a > $b, 0 if $a == $b
```

If you want it to output text, you could do something like:

```
function d($a,$b){$d=$a-$b;echo !$d?'equal':(abs($d)==$d)?'greater than':'less than';}
```

Comment: 0/0 doesn't give an error of some kind? Also, have you considered test cases near the extremes? I bet you've got a few overflow bugs.

Comment: True, but the problem isn't very well-defined as it is. I'll fix the 0/0. I haven't tested extreme cases, but maybe PHP's BC Math extension can fix those...

Comment: The numbers should be read from the user somehow, at least that's how I understand »a number inputted«.

Comment: Well, I guess PHP is out of the running now since the question requires prompting the user.

Answer (score 1):

### Objective-C - 161 chars + full string

This solution prompts the user, gets the value, and then returns the full string.

Usage - self-explanitory, it requests a with 'a?' and then once inputted, requests b with 'b?'.

```
int a,b,x;char c='A';NSLog(@"a?");scanf("%i",&a);NSLog(@"b?");scanf("%i",&b);
x=(a-b/abs(a-b)==1);NSLog(@"Integer %c is greater than integer %c.",c+!x,c+x);
```

And readable version (with whitespace)

```
int a,b,x;
char c = 'A';
NSLog(@"a?");
scanf("%i", &a);
NSLog(@"b?");
scanf("%i", &b);
x = (a-b/abs(a-b) == 1);
NSLog(@"Integer %c is greater than integer %c.", c+!x, c+x);
```

Output:

```
Computer: a?
Me: 2 
Computer: b? 
Me: 3 
Computer: Integer B is greater than integer A.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 150 characters

```
main=putStr.g.f.map read.words=<<getLine
f[a,b]|b`elem`dropWhile(/=a)[(minBound::Int)..]="BA"|0<1="AB"
g[x,y]="Integer "++x:" is greater than "++y:"."
```

I could use `Integer` and do subtraction, but I felt like dealing with overflow problems that arise from using `Int`.

Note there is a `<` in the code, but it is used to compare a constant expression (one character less than writing `True`).

Answer (score 1):

### C

```
void AgB(int a, int b) {
(( 2 * a + 1) / (2 * b + 1) == 0) ? printf("Integer B is greater than A\n") : printf("Integer A is greater than B\n");}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python alt-way

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
a, b = map(int, sys.argv[1:3])
s = '==' if (a == b) else '<' if (str(a-b)[0] == '-') else '>'
print 'a(%d) %s b(%d)' % (a, s, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If equility is not matter, just doing `sorted([A,B]) != [A,B]` should do, so

```
a=[input(),input()];print"A is "+["less","great"][sorted(a)!=a]+"er than B"
```

Tests

```
>>> a=[input(),input()];print"A is "+["less","great"][sorted(a)!=a]+"er than B"
1
2
A is lesser than B
>>> a=[input(),input()];print"A is "+["less","great"][sorted(a)!=a]+"er than B"
2
1
A is greater than B
>>> a=[input(),input()];print"A is "+["less","great"][sorted(a)!=a]+"er than B"
-1
-2
A is greater than B
>>> a=[input(),input()];print"A is "+["less","great"][sorted(a)!=a]+"er than B"
-2
-1
A is lesser than B
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 152 characters

Conforms to the letter with the specification.

No cheating with conditionals of any kind, including equality. The `abs` call probably has a conditional hidden, if I weren't golfing I would do `x/=int(math.sqrt(x*x))` as the third line.

```
i=input
x=i("A")-i("B")
x/=abs(x)
print "Integer",chr((131-x)/2),"is greater than",chr((131+x)/2)+".\n\n\n\nRules  : No Brainfuck."
```

Answer (score 1):

### BF, handles negative zero

I figured it would be fun to invent a language for the job, using characters `<` and `>` for something completely unrelated to inequality comparison.

```
# parse first number (space delimited)
+>,---------------------------------------------
[<->[->+<]]<[->+>,---------------------------------------------<<]>
>+++++++++++++[
  <<[->>>+<<<]>>----------------
  [-<<+>>]>[-<<<++++++++++>>>]<
  ,--------------------------------]
# parse second number (newline delimited)
+>,---------------------------------------------
[<->[->+<]]<[->+>,---------------------------------------------<<]>
>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++[
  <<[->>>+<<<]>>--------------------------------------
  [-<<+>>]>[-<<<++++++++++>>>]<
  ,----------]
# handle minus signs
<[<<[-<[->+<]>>[-<<+>>]<[->+<]>>-<<]>>[-<[-]<<+>>>]]
<<[-<[-]>>+<]
# compare
<+>>+[-<<-[>]>]
# report
>[[-]++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<]
<<<[[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
       +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.>]
```

For a brief summary of operators: `<` and `>` move the cursor backward/forward; `+`/`-` increment/decrement the value of the number pointed to by the cursor (hereafter referred to as "the accumulator"); `[]` iterate while the accumulator is non-null; `,` reads a byte from input to the accumulator; `.` writes the accumulator to the output.  Anything else is ignored, which provides a cool way to implement comments, that can even be made to look like comments in other scripting languages.

Handles negative numbers by checking for the following cases:

- if both numbers are signed negative, swap them
- if only one number is negative, zero it out and increment the other one
- else just leave them alone

This lets us compare zero with negative zero (`-0 < 0`).  Equality is not handled.

Funny how I/O takes more than twice the space the math does.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 86

```
a,b=input('A,B')
print 'Integer A is %s than B.'%('less'if abs(a-b)-a+b else'greater')
```

Answer (score 1):

### FORTRAN 77

I guess good old Fortran arithmetic if does not violate the requirements of the question.
Here it is

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      READ *, A
      READ *, B
      IF (B-A) 99,100,101
99    PRINT *, 'Integer A is greater than B'
      GOTO 102
100   PRINT *, 'they are equal'
      GOTO 102
101   PRINT *, 'Integer B is greater than A'
102   STOP
      END
```

Answer (score 1):

C# approach with 44 chars. I just subtract a from b and check if there is a minues in the result string:

```
bool c(int a, int b){return ("" + (b - a))[0] == 0x2d;}
```

Comment: `0x2d` could be replaced with `"-"`! -1 char

Answer (score 0):

## *C (K&R) - 49 chars*

This is indeed trivial...

```
a,b;main(){scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);printf("%d",a-b);}
```

negative result if a > b, positive if a < b, 0 if equal

**EDIT:** This answer corresponds to the very first specs of the question, when golfing was required and the output was not restricted to specific phrases.

Comment: Undefined behavior if `a-b` overflows.

Comment: @joey: tsk, tsk... too picky! The problem doesn't talk about overflows/underflows and the author didn't answer to the relative question. If you have a better suggestion which checks input against the range INT_MIN to INT_MAX without using > or < I'd be happy to see it. Until then I consider your down-vote to be rather harsh! Keep also in mind that there will always be at least one number that overflows any of the built-in data types on input, no matter what data type you choose to represent a and b.

Comment: UB is a rather special case for C and derivates, but as long as your using signed `int`s and do that subtraction you have UB. Which means that there are inputs where your method isn't guaranteed to give the correct result. Just because over-/underflows are defined in other languages doesn't make it ok to rely on that in C, in my eyes. But agreed, the question is underspecified in any case. The easiest fix, conforming to the question would probably be to make `a` and `b` unsigned (where it is defined).

Comment: @joey: but then you rule out negative numbers both on the input and on the result, which someone could legitimately consider it to be a bigger flow than not checking for overflows. Plus, you don't solve the over/underflow problem either.

Comment: @Harry, surely the best approach is to wait until the question is properly specified? That's why I've asked for clarifications. (NB I haven't downvoted any of the answers, but I may come back later and downvote anything which fails the obvious test cases).

Comment: I hear you Peter, but I feel it's unfair to down-vote for a non-solvable side-effect, without providing an equal or better solution to the given problem. Anyway, this was supposed to be fun, but it's not... I'm withdrawing my code, waiting for your better solutions...

Comment: Well, I think the spec is close enough now that I've posted a C# solution. Easily ported to C. Avoids underflow / overflow.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: alas, the only way to control over/underflow in C is to read the numbers as strings and then convert them to integers with either one of the stro?() family of functions or a custom one. That's why you saw me reacting so strongly about that down-vote :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood Joey. He's clearly talking about arithmetic overflow caused by the subtraction being e.g. `0x80000000 - 1`, not about input parsing.

Comment: I got what Joey said, but accepting that as a flaw we can also accept no input overflow check as a flow. My point is that imho both of those are away from the very essence of the given problem. I could present a full blown program taking care of a hell lot of stuff, but I think this is not what code golfing is about. Handling overflows can be easily put as a separate problem by itself (especially in C).

Comment: Harry, you can delete the post on your own. See the "delete" option next to the "edit" button?

Comment: Surely handling overflow *is* the essence of the problem. Without that it's a "challenge" consisting of "Can you tell whether an int is negative without using < or >?"

Comment: @dmckee: yes, I found it, but if it's not inappropriate for the post to stay like this, it contains some interesting commentary going on I think. Peter, we just have a different point of view, nevertheless the author changed the specs so golfing is not required any more, so full-blown programs can be presented now (which is not that interesting anymore, imho).

Comment: Delete it or revert it.  As-is it's not an answer.

Comment: I rolled back the answer.  As for the discussion, it's only broken when a and b are unreasonably large, and the asker did not specify the range of integers that must be supported.  Code Golf answers are usually not held to this high of a standard.  Oh, and you can save one character by putting `a,b` in the parameter list of `main` :-)

Comment: Thanks Joey, you made me a happy man again :) Btw, Pelles-C on the PC doesn't really like arbitrary arguments in main, actually it doesn't even compile them. I happily accept 1 char overhead in favor of portability :)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell - 18 characters

```
main=print.compare
```

Returns GT if a > b, LT if a < b.

Or since this question's output is completely unspecified, I can do

```
main=print.(-)
```

which returns a negative number if a < b, or a positive number if a > b.

EDIT: I didn't see what the exact output has to be (see below)

```
main = print.f
f x y|q==GT=g b|q==LT=g c where q=compare x y
a="Integer A is "
b="greater than"
c="less than"
e=" B."
g x=a++x++e
```

BTW, this golf sucks.

Comment: What does it return if a==b? And how does it get its input? I only ask because I know nothing about Haskell.

Comment: `compare` would return `EQ` if a==b.

Comment: This will read two Integers and print `Integer A is greater than B.`?

Comment: Dang. This doesn't count. Revised the question

Comment: Did you not see the part where it said you can't using inbuilt compare functions?

Comment: He revised the question after I submitted this.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl

```
for(0..9){
 $s.=("2"x$_)."1".("0"x(9-$_))
}
for(0..9){
  $a=$_;
  for(0..9){
   $c[$a][$_]=chop$s
  }
}
$_=<>;
$b=<>;
$l=length;
$_="0"x length$b.$_;
$b="0"x$t.$b;
for(1..$l){
 $e.=chop;$f.=chop$b
}
$g="Integer A is";
$h=" than Integer B";
for(1..$l){
 $t=$c[$_][$b];
 if($t==2){die"$g less$h"}
 if($t==0){die"$g greater$h"}
}
```

This creates a look-up array for all of the comparisons of each digit. It then takes two unsigned integers as input. It makes them the same length. It then compares them one digit at a time using the look-up array. I am sure it could be made a lot shorter.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (65)

Enter in Mozilla Firefox's Web Console:

```
'Integer A is '+(eval(prompt())>>>31?'less':'greater')+' than B.'
```

The user should separate the two signed integers (which should each fit in 31 bits) with " - ". The program takes the difference and checks the sign bit.